# Java verify digital signature in openssl

Tags: java, openssl, digital-signature, verify

Using [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/gensig.html) tutorial, I created a Java program what can sign a document with SHA256withRSA algorithm. In the output I get a public key and a signature file.

I try to verify my file with openssl, but I can't... I was searching on the net and I found that I need to have a standard .pem key maybe, so my question is: How can I convert my key to pem format? Or can I generate a .pem key in Java? And if it's a wrong way, how can I verify my signature?

Comment: Try to use a Key Store Explorer (http://keystore-explorer.org/), may be it could convert keys/certificates to a desired format

Comment: You should provide the Java code you used to produce the signature, and the OpenSSL commands you used to verify the signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PEM file contains the public key binary data encoded in base64 and splitted in lines of 64 characters. The file has also the header `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and the footer `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`

Java has not a native converter to PEM but you can use bouncycastle

```
PEMWriter pemWriter = new PEMWriter(new FileWriter(file));
pemWriter.writeObject(publicKey);
pemWriter.flush();
pemWriter.close();
```

Alternatively you can verify a signature with openssl using a binary key format using

```
  -keyform DER
```

Then save the content of your publicKey in a file

```
 byte publicKeyDer[] = publicKey.getEncoded()
```